# Questions regarding the Google Oauth app verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

So we've completed the implementation of the google calendar integration in our pre-production application.

Now, we need to submit the Oauth app for verification and I had a few questions:

1. Can we create the demo app in our pre-production application or does it need to be created in the production application? *[the issue with recording video in production app is that we can't deploy the feature to production app until the Oauth app is verified by Google as we don't want users to see an unusable feature. ]*
2. If we have both mobile app and web app where we've integrated the Oauth app, do we need to create demo videos in both apps or can we just create video using either mobile or web app?
3. We're using the same Oauth app(*that we're going to submit for verification*) for our pre-production environments as well right now. Is this a valid practice?

Comment: I don't exactly grasp what's the issue here - technically it's possible to do both thins you mentioned.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I assumed that the demo video needed to be made on the  production app. And Regarding my second question, I was thinking of only making the demo video through the web app.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: At that point you have two possibilities: create a video with demo app or later on when the app is verified. It's totally up to you.

Comment: @Wojtek_B I think the only option is to create a demo video using out pre-production app (demo application) and see of google appoves it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related but rather related to Googles authorization process.

Comment: @DaImTo Sure if it isn't the right platform for this question, I'm closing it. Could you point me to the right place to ask this question? Thank you.